# Create a list of objects from dynamically loaded dll on runtime

Tags: c#, oop, dynamic, dll

I have a dll that is loaded on runtime. I am trying to create instances of each Type from dynamically loaded dll on runtime, and add these instances into a List. All classes in the dll are based from AYClass, so they should be added into the List succesfully. But I am having such an error like below

```
Exception thrown: 
'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException' in Microsoft.CSharp.dll

Additional information: An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation
```

My code is like below...

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\Library\CurrencyData.dll");
List<AYClass> listObjects = new List<AYClass>();
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (type.BaseType.ToString().Contains("AYClass"))
    {
        dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        listObjects.Add(c); // ******* Exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use `dynamic` when you know the base type? Don't do that. Use var instead:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\Library\CurrencyData.dll");
List<AYClass> listObjects = new List<AYClass>();
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes())
{
    if (type.BaseType.ToString().Contains("AYClass"))
    {
        var c = (AYClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        listObjects.Add(c);
    }
}
```

In general C# is a type safe language, so using `dynamic` should be exceptional. Also be sure, that in your dynamic loaded dll and in your "loader" they use the exact same base-class. In any other case casting the instance will fail.

Furthermore you could replace this line: `if (type.BaseType.ToString().Contains("AYClass"))` with comparing the type and not its name. This is not very safe, because a class with the same name can be declared in different assemblies and or namespaces in the same assembly.

Comment: hi, if you use "var", you cannot use listObjects.add(c). you have to cast object type to AYClass

Comment: @ayilmaz You can use `AYClass c = (AYClass)Activator.CreateInstance(type);` var is just a shorthand to hide the type. `var` still works though.

Comment: @BendEg, it gives me this error Unable to cast object of type 'AY.CurrencyData.Model.Currency' to type 'AY.CurrencyData.Model.AYClass'.

Comment: Yep, your problem is that you DON'T have the same base class. Are they declared in different assemblies?

Comment: yeah, they are declared in different assemblies

Comment: That can't work, even if the code is equal. Because they are not equal (signature, ...) Be sure you only have ONE implementation. Maybe put it into a kind of core assembly which is used in your dynamically loaded assembly and in your "loader" part.

Comment: creating a core assembly is unnecessary for our need. thank you very much for your help. I will accepted it as answered